# Weird behavior of itertools.chain.from_iterable

Tags: python, python-itertools

Consider this code snippet:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> foo = [0]
>>> for i in (1, 2):
...     bar = (range(a, a+i) for a in foo)
...     foo = chain(*list(bar))
...
>>> list(foo)
[0, 1]
```

This makes sense - in the first iteration of the loop, `bar` is equivalent to `iter([[0]])` and foo evaluates to `chain([0])`, which is equivalent to `iter([0])`. Then, in the second iteration of the loop, `bar` is now equivalent to `iter([[0, 1]])` and foo becomes `iter([0, 1])`. That's why `list(foo)` is `[0, 1]`.

I also get the same result for `list(foo)` when I use `foo = sum(list(bar), [])` rather than of `chain(*list(bar))`.

Now consider this code snippet:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> foo = [0]
>>> for i in (1, 2):
...     bar = (range(a, a+i) for a in foo)
...     foo = chain.from_iterable(bar)
...
>>> list(foo)
[0, 1, 1, 2]
```

As you can see, the only difference is the `foo = chain.from_iterable(bar)` line, that uses [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) rather than `itertools.chain`.

It seems to me that `itertools.chain(*list(iterable))` is roughly equivalent to `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable)`, however it's not the case here. So why is the final result different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that in `chain(*list(bar))`, bar is exhausted immediately, whereas in `chain.from_iterable(bar)`, it's not.  And in the definition of `bar`, `i` is used, which is late-binding: it picks up the value of `i` not at the time of definition, but from the name `i` at the time it's evaluated.

IOW, when you use `foo = chain.from_iterable(bar)`, `bar` is not evaluated yet.  When you then call `list(foo)`, and it "calls" `bar`, the `i` in the definition picks up the value that the name `i` *currently refers to* -- which is 2.

So if we change `i` manually, we should be able to change the result appropriately:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> foo = [0]
>>> for i in (1, 2):
...         bar = (range(a, a+i) for a in foo)
...         foo = chain.from_iterable(bar)
...     
>>> i = 10
>>> list(foo)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the use of generators and the delayed evaluation of `foo = chain.from_iterable(bar)`. The two programs would be equivalent if you changed this line to be `foo = chain.from_iterable(list(bar))`, which forces the evaluation of the bar generator to ground foo in concrete values.

Otherwise, as written, the two programs are semantically different in that the former applies chain to a list while the second applies chain to a generator which can be thought of as a function handle in some respects, which defers execution until the final `list(foo)` is called after the loop finishes.

[This answer was tested in Python 3, where range is a generator. It may behave differently in Python 2.x where range returns the entire list...]